# I want my html table to give the result shown in pic

Tags: html

I want to get the result shown below in pic but my code isn't giving me that result

```
<form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="Uname">User Name:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="Uname" name="Uname"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="pass">Password:</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" id="pass" name="pass"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" name="remember-me">Remember my user name and password</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Log me in"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

I want this result :
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B68Zr.jpg)

but i keep on getting this :
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BogAI.jpg)

Comment: More CSS styles, less table for layout.

Comment: yes you are right but the image I sent is doing this without css. so it would be great if you could tell me how to do this with only html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `colspan="2"` attribute to previous row:

```
<td colspan="2" align="right">
  <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" name="remember-me">
  Remember my user name and password
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead of `table` tag.
It is more flexible and scalable.

```css
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    
    width: 75%;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.align-left {
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.align-right {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.inpt {
    width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div class="content">

            <div class="row">
                <label for="Uname">User Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="Uname" name="Uname" class="inpt">
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <label for="pass">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="inpt">
            </div>

            <div class="row align-left">
                <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" name="remember-me">
                Remember my user name and password
            </div>

            <div class="row align-right">
                <input type="submit" value="Log me in">
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is to use `flex-direction: column;` and `flex-direction: row;` to emulate your table, but expanding or shrinking just the way you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. That's a nice way to do it too